# Prove an inequality for a specific Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a \in \mathbb R$

Consider the differential equation

$$\frac{d^9y}{dt^9}-\dfrac{dy}{dt}+ay=0 \tag 1$$

suppose $\varphi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a solution of $(1)$ on $\mathbb R$.

Prove that there exists some $N\in \mathbb N$, $K \in (0,\infty)$ such that

$$\left[\sum_{j=0}^N\left(\frac{d^j\varphi(0)}{dt^j}\right)\right]^2\exp(-K|x|)
\le\sum_{j=0}^N \left(\frac{d^j\varphi(x)}{dt^j}\right)^2
\le \left[\sum_{j=0}^N \left(\frac{d^j\varphi(0)}{dt^j}\right)\right]^2 \exp(K|x|)$$

for any $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Write $$Z=\begin{pmatrix}
y^{8}(x) \\
y^{7}(x) \\
\vdots \\
y(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$ The differential equation can be rewritten as $Z^\prime=AZ$ where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots &  1 &-a \\
1 & 0 & 0 &  \dots &  0 \\
0 & 1 &  0 &  \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots &  \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dots &  0  &  1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Now you can apply techniques on order one linear differential equations of several of variables to find lower and upper bounds of the solutions.

Comment: Do you mean solve the system of ODE?